# Convert scala.math.BigDecimal to java.math.BigDecimal?

Tags: scala, bigdecimal

How do I convert a `scala.math.BigDecimal` to `java.math.BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No need to double-convert to and from string.

```
val sb = scala.math.BigDecimal(12345)
val jb = sb.bigDecimal
```

`scala.math.BigDecimal` is just a very simple wrapper around `java.math.BigDecimal`, and it provides wrapped value as one of fields.